# How to record and save video of Gym environment

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, dqn

I have trained a DQN agent and I want to record and save a video of a single episode using gym.wrappers.RecordVideo. Here's my code so far:

```
from gym.wrappers import RecordVideo
env = gym.make("AlienDeterministic-v4", render_mode="human")
env = preprocess_env(env)  # method with some other wrappers
env = RecordVideo(env, 'video', episode_trigger=lambda x: x == 2)

for episode in range(4):
        state = env.reset()[0]
        done = False
        while not done:
            action = self.select_smart_action(state)
            next_state, reward, done, _, _ = env.step(action)
            state = next_state
            env.render()

    env.close()
```

My code so far creates a directory called "video" but it doesn't create or save any videos. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/wrappers/record_video.py) you may need to call the `start_video_recorder()` method prior to the first step.

All in all:

```py
from gym.wrappers import RecordVideo
env = gym.make("AlienDeterministic-v4", render_mode="human")
env = preprocess_env(env)  # method with some other wrappers
env = RecordVideo(env, 'video', episode_trigger=lambda x: x == 2)
env.start_video_recorder()

for episode in range(4):
        state = env.reset()[0]
        done = False
        while not done:
            action = self.select_smart_action(state)
            next_state, reward, done, _, _ = env.step(action)
            state = next_state
            env.render()

    env.close()
```

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. Also there should be env.reset() before env.start_video_recorder()

Comment: True, I totally forgot

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue, as the documentation is a bit lacking.

Anyway, you forgot to set the `render_mode` to `rgb_mode` and **stopping** the recording. I marked the relevant code with `###`

```py
import gymnasium as gym

###
# create a temporary variable with our env, which will use rgb_array as render mode. This mode is supported by the RecordVideo-Wrapper
tmp_env = gym.make("ALE/Pong-v5", render_mode="rgb_array")

# wrap the env in the record video
env = gym.wrappers.RecordVideo(env=tmp_env, video_folder="/home/viewviewview/WS2023/deeplearning", name_prefix="test-video", episode_trigger=lambda x: x % 2 == 0)

# env reset for a fresh start
observation, info = env.reset()

###
# Start the recorder
env.start_video_recorder()


# AI logic
for _ in range(1000):
    action = env.action_space.sample()  # agent policy that uses the observation and info
    observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()

    if terminated or truncated:
        observation, info = env.reset()

####
# Don't forget to close the video recorder before the env!
env.close_video_recorder()

# Close the environment
env.close()
```